# Search from all field

Tags: php, mysql, regex, select

I have a string with separated by commas like (`delhi,110005,Hospital`) and I want to search like that:

```
$string="delhi,110005,Hospital";

SELECT * FROM `hospitals` WHERE CONCAT(",", `sub_city_name`, ",") REGEXP ",($string),"
```

It works for only one field but when I pass multiple fields its not working.

Comment: You want to search what? Can you be specific?

Comment: Can you please show the table structure and  a couple of rows?

Comment: actuary i have a table fields(city_name,sub_city_name,hospital_name,pincode) and i have a string with separated by commas and i want to search data from all field with %like%

Comment: i want search like this


SELECT * FROM `hospitals` WHERE CONCAT(",", `sub_city_name`, `city_name`, `hospital_name`, ",") REGEXP ",($string),"

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your search string has values for fields in a sequence. For example if you want to search against all fields i-e

**`(city_name,sub_city_name,hospital_name,pincode)`**

your search string should contain values in that sequence as well i-e

```
$string="Delhi,Sub City,Hospital,110005";
$string2="Sub City,Hospital,110005";
$string3="Hospital,110005";
$string4="Delhi,Sub City";
```

If my assumptions are correct, following query may work for you.

```
SELECT *
FROM `hospitals`
WHERE  CONCAT(`city_name`,',',`sub_city_name`,',',`hospital_name`,',',`pincode`)
LIKE '%{string_goes_here}%';
```

[SQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4019a/17/0)

Answer (score 0):

If there are no commas in the individual fields, use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) for testing whether an item is in a commalist.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use something like following:

```
SELECT * FROM `hospitals` WHERE field LIKE '%delhi,110005,Hospital%';
```

Comment: actuary i have a table fields(city_name,sub_city_name,hospital_name,pincode) and i have a string with separated by commas and i want to search data from all field with %like%

Comment: can you share a couple of complete rows of data of actual table?